# Alternative to Kotlin Coroutines in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there an alternative to Kotlin Coroutines in Java? I have Kotlin code in which I want to perform facial recognition on one dispatcher, while updating the bounding boxes on the other. I tried to automatically convert the code to Java, but the coroutines part was not converted.

The code is something like this:

```kotlin
withContext( Dispatchers.Default ) {
    //perform face recognition
}

withContext( Dispatchers.Main ) {
    boundingBoxOverlay.faceBoundingBoxes = predictions
    boundingBoxOverlay.invalidate()
    isProcessing.set(false)
}
```

Comment: The "easiest" is to just use some other thread. That will require to rearchitect some possibly large part of your code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but thread management in this case would be very difficult.a and there will be a lot of overhead. Is there any way to use the koltin coroutines in java code? @al3c

Comment: Coroutines work via the koltin compiler rewriting some code so, no coroutines for you in Java. Maybe the question here is 'why are you trying to convert kotlin to java?'. Oh and by the way you can keep a few files in Kotlin and rewrite the rest in Java.

Comment: Because the app is written in java. I am adding the feature of Face recognition and it requires coroutines to run concurrently to constantly update the frames and recognize the faces.

Answer (score 4):

For the most part...you can't.

Kotlin coroutines rely on transformations performed by the compiler recognizing `suspend` function calls and handling them specially, tracking their state and resuming them correctly.  The Java compiler doesn't do this.

This, unfortunately, means you'll probably end up needing to substantially restructure your code to something callback-based.  The best way to do that is going to depend on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to implement concurrent behaviour.
The following could help, but the exact solution would depend on how you use the methods too. The `withContext()` will run both methods concurrently and wait for both of them to finish.

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

public final void withContext(){
 final Future<?> futureFacial = this.executorService.submit(this::withContextFacial);
 final Future<?> futureBounding = this.executorService.submit(this::withContextBoundingBoxes);
 futureFacial.get();
 futureBounding.get();

}
private final withContextFacial( ) {
    //perform face recognition }

private final withContextBoundingBoxes() {
    boundingBoxOverlay.faceBoundingBoxes = predictions
    boundingBoxOverlay.invalidate()
    isProcessing.set(false) }
```

Kotlin has language level support for coroutines while Java doesn't. That means that you have to workaround this fact and model the solution in another way.
There are multiple solutions to this already in the Java SRE. Such as: Threads, ExecutorService, ForkJoin.
And then multiple libraries and approaches outside JRE such as the Actor model or reactive programming.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

Java compiler does not support suspendable computations for its threads. It only supports synchronous (Blocking) computations only.

But Java language has something close similar to the kotlin coroutine is **Thread pool**.

(Thread pool - a managed collection of threads that runs tasks in parallel from a queue. New tasks are executed on existing threads as those threads become idle).

Comment: Unfortunately, a Thread <> a Job, so Java thread pools are still not analogous to Kotlin coroutines

Answer (score -2):

You could write your coroutines, than decompile code and use java-class for coroutine, but it seems to be so non-flexible approach, also you should deal with continuations.

In case of java - just use RXJava instead of coroutines, it is well known approach for concurrency